# Win8 GridView items are out of bound

Tags: c#, wpf, winrt-xaml

When I'm placing a semantic zoom control with GridView inside my items are falling out of it as on the screenshot.

[image: grid view]

I put my data items into a wrap panel and expecting it will wrap them. But for some reason it does not. What is wrong here?

Here is how my gridview defined in xaml:

```
 <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                    <GridView ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" 
                              ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PatientMediaFileBigItemTemplate}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource patientMediaFiles} }" 
                              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                              SelectionMode="None"
                              Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemClick="MediaFileIcon_Click"
                              >
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <controls:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Width="Auto"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <GridView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" FontSize="28" Foreground="Black"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle>
                        </GridView.GroupStyle>
                    </GridView>
                </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
```

Comment: I think it's because your `WrapPanel` likely has auto height and no maximum rows. You may have to do those calculations on your own unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding group style along group header style

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of your wrap panel you need to do calculations according to your requirement in arrangeOverride and measureOverride method and try to set the child items viewport and its offset.